# Embedded Jetty 9 HttpException equivalent?

Tags: eclipse, embedded-jetty, httpexception

We are Upgrading to Jetty 9 from Jetty 6, but in our previous code we are throwing  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpException, but I see that this Class is removed in 9.x. Is there any equivalent of this class or should I define a new class with the same content to use it in my code?

Comment: What is the purpose of you throwing that exception?  Why not just use the [`javax.servlet.ServletException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Jetty 7.6 was the first version to not have `HttpException`.

It was removed as part of commit [d81f9c1e](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/b9a2661a4e14b8c3dab24b310ddb774fd81f9c1e)

The purpose of `HttpException` was limited to reporting really bad HTTP parsing issues with bad requests (all of which would result in a `400 Bad Request`).  That implementation was changed to use `HttpParser.badMessage()` instead, as that will properly set the connection state, and then allow implementations of `HttpHandler.badMessage()` to log or produce whatever response is desired, afterwords resulting in a forced connection close.

Without this change, it was not possible to log `400 Bad Request` in the access log, and customize the error 400 response message.

There is no equivalent exception for `HttpException` present in Jetty 7.6+.

It was an internal class anyway, not meant for you to be using.

What are you attempting to accomplish by using that?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced  that code with HttpException, with BadMessageException, hope that would be fine....